# Can I reset a Meteor Session variable to it's Default value?

Tags: meteor

I want to reset a Meteor Session variable to it's default value - is that possible?

Example:

```
Session.setDefault 'foo', 'bar'
Session.get 'foo' # => 'bar'
Session.set 'foo', 'boing'
Session.get 'foo' # => 'boing'
delete Session.keys['foo']
Session.get 'foo' # => undefined
```

But I want something like `resetToDefault` which would then do (after the above):

```
Session.get 'foo' # => undefined
Session.resetToDefault()
Session.get 'foo' # => 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this code :

```
function MyReactiveDict(keys){
    ReactiveDict.call(this,keys);
    this.defaults={};
}
MyReactiveDict.prototype=Object.create(ReactiveDict.prototype);

_.extend(MyReactiveDict.prototype,{
    setDefault:function(key,value){
        ReactiveDict.prototype.setDefault.call(this,key,value);
        this.defaults[key]=value;
    },
    resetToDefault:function(key){
        this.set(key,this.defaults[key]);
    }
});

MySession=new MyReactiveDict();
```

Session is an instance of `ReactiveDict`, so what I did was defining our own `MyReactiveDict` by inheriting the regular `ReactiveDict`, add the functionality we want, and finally declare `MySession` as an instance of `MyReactiveDir`.

`MySession` would pass the tests you described in your answer.

I think you can even safely overwrite `Session` in your app by preserving already defined keys with the following code :

```
Session=new MyReactiveDict(Session.keys);
```

That's because the `ReactiveDict` constructor can take an array of existing keys to start with.

You need to `meteor add reactive-dict` to your application for this code to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no feature like `resetToDefault`.

`Session.setDefault` is implemented like this:

```
setDefault: function (key, value) {
    var self = this;
    // for now, explicitly check for undefined, since there is no
    // ReactiveDict.clear().  Later we might have a ReactiveDict.clear(), in which case
    // we should check if it has the key.
    if (self.keys[key] === undefined) {
      self.set(key, value);
    }
  },
```

[Source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js)

What you can do is to create js object with all defaults and then once you would like to reset you simply access that object get proper value for key and use `Session.set(key, value)`.

```
defaultsObject = {
  A : 1,
  B : 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: Just create a function where you set all your session variables. Then you call this very function.

```
resetToDefault = function() {
    Session.set('expertMode', false);
    Session.set('displayNavigation', false);
    Session.set('displaySidebar', true);
    Session.set('currentEvent', null);
    Session.set('activeLayers', []);
};

resetToDefault();
```

If you make sure that your function is defined under client/lib, so it will be called before everything else, you can also use it instead of Session.setDefault().

After that you can call resetToDefault() from anywhere within the client.